Screen auto-rotate is always 90 degrees off
I have an Asus q502L running 24.04.1 and the auto rotate works, except that it is always exactly 90 degrees off. No matter how you turn the laptop, the display is rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise from where it should be.
I can lock it in place, but it seems like, since it is clearly talking to the rotation sensor, there should be a way to correct this. Is there?
Thanks in advance.

I worked out a way.

vim /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb
Find a similar device (Q551L instead of Q502L in this case)
Add a second line piggybacking the Q551L setting into the Q502L one.


go into Ubuntu's "Display" settings, and check that 'Rotation' is set to none. if it is set to anything else, then both the auto-rotate and the "Display" settings rotate functions may be conflicting.

Thanks for the suggestion.  There is no "Rotation" setting unfortunately.
